# Import SVG file into multiple divs using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to import svg file into multiple divs on the same page. The code I have is working, but for the first div only. Here is the code:

```js
const status = document.getElementById('status');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
if (window.FileList && window.File && window.FileReader) {
  document.getElementById('file-selector').addEventListener('change', event => {
    output.src = '';
    status.textContent = '';
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (!file.type) {
      status.textContent = 'Error: The File.type property does not appear to be supported on this browser.';
      return;
    }
    if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
      status.textContent = 'Error: The selected file does not appear to be an image.'
      return;
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', event => {
      output.src = event.target.result;
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>Import file</h1>
<input type="file" id="file-selector">
<p id="status"></p>

<div>
  <img id="output">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="output">
</div>
<div>
  <img id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribute **should not** have duplicate values. Each element **should** have a **unique** value for `id`. If you want to select multiple elements, Use `class` instead of `id`.

```js
  const status = document.getElementById('status');

  // returns the array of elements
  const outputs = document.querySelectorAll('.output');
  
  if (window.FileList && window.File && window.FileReader) {
    document.getElementById('file-selector').addEventListener('change', event => {
    
      // get each element (ES6)
      outputs.forEach(output => {
      
        // your logic for each element
      
      });
    }); 
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="output">
</div>
 <div>
  <img class="output">
</div>
 <div>
  <img class="output">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to fit your solution, but I can't make it work.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Id's (which should be unique for every element use classes)
Like so:

```
<div>
  <img class="output">
</div>
 <div>
  <img class="output">
</div>
 <div>
  <img class="output">
</div>
```

select it with  `document.querySelector(".output")` and add your svg's